# How to prevent JSON parsing errors: my RootObject class defines a property as "long" but sometimes I get an "object"

Tags: c#, json

I am consuming some RESTFUL JSON data and it works just fine (this is financial data for the stock market). I have defined my class with all of the properties in it and defined those properties as "string" or "long" or "double", etc. for whatever the expected result will be.

One of the properties in my class is called "marketCap" and it has been defined as a "long" type. However, depending upon which stock symbol that I am referencing, instead of a "long", the JSON response will be an "Object", specifically "null".

I have defined the property as such:

```
public long marketCap { get; set; }
```

Here is the JSON I get returned occasionally:

```
"marketCap":null,
```

Most of the time it returns a proper long response such as:

```
"marketCap":18393473
```

When I get an incorrect property type returned it crashes the program.

How can I test the JSON response before I parse the data (or when I am parsing the data)? It seems that when the JSON data is parsed by my RootObject formatter, that's when it hits this property that should be a "long" but it isn't and so it crashes.

```
RootObject priceData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: define the property as a Nullable<long>

Comment: examine the data before deserialize it. if it's a null issue and the marketCap actually have nulls then you change the datatype to `long?` which is nullable (accepts nulls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the marketCap property as Nullable. Nullable types can represent all the values of an underlying type T, and an additional null value. For example,

```
public class RootObject
{
    // Other Properties
    public long? marketCap {get;set;}
    // Other Properties
}
```

Example,

```
var json = @"{'marketCap':null}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Where RootObject is defined as

```
public class RootObject
{
    public long? marketCap {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This worked for me very well. I knew there must have been a simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this to a nullable long in your class definition.

```
public long? marketCap { get; set; }
```

The downside of this is that your code will now have to check if the object is null every time.

```
if (marketCap != null)
{
  // do something with Convert.ToInt64(marketCap)
}
else
{
  // do what you need to do if null was supplied
}
```